# How could I modify "_vars.scss" file in a HTML5Up package?

Tags: html, sass

I downloaded a package (HTML + CSS + JS) from this link: https://html5up.net/landed

And I tried quite a lot of times to modify the "_vars.scss" file, because I want to change the color of buttons ("accent1" in the file). And I always fail. It seems that whatever I do to the "_vars.scss" file, its impact on the webpage remains the same.

So what is wrong here? And what should I do if I want to change the color pallette of the page? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `_vars.scss` file is a partial (as denoted by the underscore), so you'll need to recompile `main.scss` (which imports the partial on line 1) for any changes you make to `_vars.scss` to show up in your CSS output.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. This really helps. And sorry for my late appreciation ; )